# Overriding current time/'now' in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, date, time

In our system we occasionally need to simulate things as if they were run at a particular date and time and that needs to be reflected in the database.

Is there a way in SQLite to override it's concept of the current time/'now'?

e.g. SELECT DATETIME('now', 'localtime') should return a datetime we've set, not the system datetime. Note: The queries are user configured so not something we are writing ourselves.

Obviously we don't want to override the whole system clock but it's fine if this works on a per connection basis.

I've tried searching but have only seen suggestions about overriding the default date and time functions but I have no idea how I can do that in a safe way.

Comment: A script should always have an option for the date, and if that option is absent, then use the current date.If this is not possible, the only way I can imagine is to put a copy of the base on a non production machine, change the date *on that machine* run the script, extract the new rows and copy them back to the main database.

Comment: I updated my original question to clarify a bit. The problem is that we cannot just change the queries because they are configured by the user, we need to instead set the system time in the connection string or something so each query knows when the real 'now' is